# is there a way to partition a result set with exportToCsv?

Tags: powershell

I am throwing a query which returns 1M600k results, and I want to throw it to an excel file, I've tried to do it with export to csv but I had no luck because it is topped to little over 1M is there a way to partition that result set that when it fills one sheet it passes the rest to another sheet?

this is my code, without showing the query, the credentials haha, thank you for your help

```
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout=1200 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
return $DataSet.Tables[0] | select * | Export-CSV "C:\Users\MX02689\Desktop\DemandaAlta.csv" -NoTypeInformation 
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could "buffer" the query results manually and then export the chunks to separate files as you fill the buffer:

```
$sheetSize = 100000 # Let's do 100K records per sheet
$buffer = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new($sheetSize)

# ...

$sheetNumber = 1
$DataSet.Tables[0] |ForEach-Object{
  if($buffer.Count -eq $sheetSize){
    # buffer is full, time to flush
    $buffer |Select * |Export-Csv "C:\Users\MX02689\Desktop\DemandaAlta_sheet_${sheetNumber}.csv" -NoTypeInformation 
    $sheetNumber += 1
    $buffer.Clear()
  }

  $buffer.Add($_)
}

if($buffer.Count -eq $sheetSize){
  # buffer still has data, time to flush one last time
    $buffer |Select * |Export-Csv "C:\Users\MX02689\Desktop\DemandaAlta_sheet_${sheetNumber}.csv" -NoTypeInformation 
}
```

Which, for >1.6M records, will result in files `DemandaAlta_sheet_1.csv` through `DemandaAlta_sheet_17.csv` created.

Comment: Hi, and for example if I am trying to put 1M as sheetsize, so that way I can have 1M in one file and the rest in other, but it only makes one file, and the rest is ignored is there a way to do that? sorry to bother you again, and thank you for all your help :)

Comment: @HeberSolis `$DataSet.Tables[0] |Select -First 1000000 |Export-Csv ...`

Comment: but then I would remove the whole buffer thing?  because that would only happen if buffer.count -eq 1000000 doesn't it? :/

Comment: Yeah, the buffering is completely unnecessary is you just want to export the first N records and nothing more - `$DataSet.Tables[0] |Select -First 1000000 |Export-Csv ...` is all you need for that